# How to get a content of a hidden file over https?

Tags: vmware-esx

Now I am successfully using WebClient.DownloadString to get file content from ESX server. My URI is something like:

```
https://<ip>/folder/<file-path>?dcPath=ha-datacenter&dsName=<datastore-name>
```

**But how can I get a content of a hidden file (e.g. '.myfile')?** I have the 404 or Not Found error message when I receive a response from the server. And nothing happens when I open this url in my browser. May be there is exist a parameter like 'dcPath' (datacenter path) or 'dsName' (datastore name) for ESX https request to receive a content of a hidden file. Or may be there are ESX server's settings that enable receiving hidden files through the https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web servers usually identify file types based on the file extension and treat them accordingly... and will refuse to serve unknown files. I don't know if this is your case, but the web server could very well not be configured to handle a file called ".something", which in its view would be of a unknown type (regardless of it being hidden or not).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the answer is that I can't download a hidden file over https. The details are [here](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1597748#1597748).